# Read Oracle database from Azure Elastic Database Job

Tags: sql-server, oracle, azure, azure-sql-database

In onprem SQL Server you could add a remote database server such as Oracle as a Linked Server, and use in a SQL Server Job Agent job.

Is this possible in Azure SQL Database using [Elastic Database Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/elastic-jobs-overview)? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Azure SQL Database (PaaS) a concept like a linked server does not exist, however on [Azure Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-transact-sql-information) (PaaS) you can have linked servers but they support limited number of targets. Supported targets: SQL Server and Azure SQL Database. Not supported targets: files, Analysis Services, and other RDBMS (including Oracle).

You may want to consider creating a SQL Server VM on Azure (IaaS) or using Azure Data Factory.

Comment: Trying to decouple from VM (whether Azure or onprem). So ADF would be what we'll have to do then.

Comment: The concept of incremental loading and watermarks may be useful for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-powershell